# pandoc or libreoffice for multiple .docs to pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf, docx, pandoc

I am trying to batch convert documents from .docx to .pdf in R. My documents are contained in the following file structure: Level 1 Folders --> Level 2 Folders ---> Files
Within the level 2 folders, some files are already pdf and others are document.

I'm wondering if there is a way to set up pandoc file path command that it reads which files are .docx within a level 2 folder and then converts those.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution not with pandoc but with RDCOMClient. I thought it might be of interest to you.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_PDF <- "D:\\temp.pdf"
path_Word <- "D:\\temp.docx"

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

############################
#### Open word document ####
############################
doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_Word),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)


###################################
#### Save word document as pdf ####
###################################
wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs(path_PDF, FileFormat = 17) # FileFormat = 17 saves as .PDF
doc$Close()
wordApp$Quit() # quit wordApp
```

You can get a list of the .docx file you want to convert and use a "for loop".